# Brief Question about Logistics of Integrals

Tags: integration

Is this a proper way to define a function $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1+x^2} dt$?

My question is: are we allowed to define functions in which the variable $x$ is inside the integrand and in the upper/lower limits of integration?

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Such integrals are often performed in multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it makes sense.
Note that in your case the factor $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ is a costant with respect to $t$ so you can leave it outside the integral.

Moreover in many case you can transform the domain is something that not depends explicitly on $x$. For example  in you case we have the substitution $$z = \frac{t}{x}$$
It follows that :

- when $t=x$ you have $z = 1$
- when $t=0$ you have $ z = 0$.

Since  $\mathrm d t = x\ \mathrm d z  $ we can rewrite $F(x)$ as

$$F(x) =  \int_0^1 \frac{xz}{1+x^2}  x\ \mathrm d z = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \int_0^1 z \ \mathrm d z = \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} $$